# Azure windows container (docker swarm) overlay network can't reach internal IP's

Tags: azure, docker, networking, network-programming, docker-swarm

I created a swarm cluster and everything seems to work. I created an overlay network, can attach services to the network and publish port and reach them from outside.
I can reach "the internet" too i.e. google.com, however, I can't reach internal IP's, for example host nodes or domain controllers (they are resolved by DNS). 
If I attach it to the default ingress network I can reach the internal nodes, as well as the internet but can't reach containers on other hosts.

Comment: Hi. Did you solve your issue?

Comment: Not really - though it seems to have to do with the HNS network from windows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically everything works as it's supposed except on the managers that can't route to internal ips from within the containers.
Still I don't know why this happens